# Using plotly animation frame in event_data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to filter a plot in shiny based on the selected frame in an animated plotly plot (for this app: http://www.seabbs.co.uk/shiny/ExploreGlobalTB/#). Is this possible using the current event_data implementation (for reference: https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/linking-views-with-shiny.html)? From reading through the ropensci GitHub I don't think this has been implemented. If not any other suggestions for getting this functionality?

A working example of reactivity between plots (on clicking) is as follows (warning this code uses getTBinR and will pull WHO TB data from here (http://www.who.int/tb/country/data/download/en/).

```
#install.packages(shiny)
library(shiny)
# install.packages(devtools)
# devtools::install_github("seabbs/getTBinR", ref = "improved_interactive_plots")
library(getTBinR)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("map_tb_burden"),
  verbatimTextOutput("country")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Make map of metric
output$map_tb_burden <- renderPlotly({

  map <- map_tb_burden(interactive = TRUE, year = c(2000:2016))

})

#Get country clicked on map
country <- reactive({
  country <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "WorldMap")

  country <- country$key[[1]]
})

output$country <- renderText({
  if (is.null(country())) {
    "Select a country for more information"
  } else {
    paste0("Showing data for ", country())
  }
})

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The frame for this data is Year in the ggplot object which is then converted using plotly (mapping function code: https://github.com/seabbs/getTBinR/blob/improved_interactive_plots/R/map_tb_burden.R). Ideally I would be able to use the event_data framework, but failing this would it be possible to select the current frame from the plotly object?

A second example modified from MLavoie's answer. Just to clarify the aim is to extract both country on clicking and year as this is animated over. Both examples extract country on clicking, the following makes it clear that year is not changing dynamically as it is animated.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(getTBinR)

tb_burden <- get_tb_burden()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("map_tb_burden"),
  dataTableOutput("country")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Make map of metric
  output$map_tb_burden <- renderPlotly({


    key <- tb_burden$iso3

    g <- list(
      showframe = FALSE,
      showcoastlines = FALSE,
      projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
    )


    plot_ly(data  = tb_burden, frame = ~year, type = 'choropleth', z = ~e_inc_100k, text = ~country, color = ~e_inc_100k, colors = "Reds", locations = ~iso3, key = key) %>% 
      layout(geo = g)

  })

  #Get country clicked on map
  countryB <- reactive({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    ff <- data.frame(d[3])
    ff
  })



  output$country <- renderDataTable({

    d <- event_data("plotly_click")

    #   if (is.null(d))
    #    return(NULL)

    withProgress(message = 'Click on a country', {
      validate(
        need(d, 'Click on a country!')
      )



      testing <- tb_burden %>% filter(iso3 == countryB()$key) 
      testing

    })

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want. Do you need to use map_tb_burden? or ploy_geo is fine? Are you trying to extract some info from the map when you click on one country?

Comment: Apologies. The final use case is to use this function, but an example with any other approach would be great. 

Currently the above code extracts the country level data on clicking. I am also looking for a way to extract the current animation frame. This could either be with the same event data call, a second event data call or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you want but here is something. Instead of using `map_tb_burden` I use `plot_ly` for the graphic. In the example, it only prints text but you can decide to plot instead.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(getTBinR)

tb_burden <- get_tb_burden()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("map_tb_burden"),
  sliderInput("animation", "Looping Animation:", min = 2000, max = 2016, value = 2000, step = 1, animate= animationOptions(interval=1000, loop=FALSE, playButton = "PLAY", pauseButton = "PAUSE")),
  dataTableOutput("country")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Make map of metric
  output$map_tb_burden <- renderPlotly({


    key <- tb_burden$iso3

    g <- list(
      showframe = FALSE,
      showcoastlines = FALSE,
      projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
    )

    tb_burdenb <- tb_burden %>% filter(year == input$animation) 
    key <- tb_burdenb$iso3

    plot_ly(data  = tb_burdenb, type = 'choropleth', z = ~e_inc_100k, text = ~country, color = ~e_inc_100k, colors = "Reds", locations = ~iso3, key = key) %>% 
      layout(geo = g)

  })



  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Animation"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$animation)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 



  #Get country clicked on map
  countryB <- reactive({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    ff <- data.frame(d[3])
    ff
  })



  output$country <- renderDataTable({

    d <- event_data("plotly_click")

    #   if (is.null(d))
    #    return(NULL)

    withProgress(message = 'Click on a country', {
      validate(
        need(d, 'Click on a country!')
      )



      testing <- tb_burden %>% filter(iso3 == countryB()$key) %>% filter(year == input$animation) 
      testing

    })

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this!

So this implements the same functionality as in my question. Reactive filtering based on clicking on a country, although with a different (and possibly more elegant) solution.

The map in my example has time as a dimension (using the frame argument to animate over the year). I have added this to your example (plus changing the metric to make the changes over time more obvious). I am looking to extract the year dynamically as it is animated, on top of the country on clicking. The desired outcome would be country on click and year as it is animated.

Comment: @Sam Abbott. see edits. I have added a couple of things to the code, including a selectInput to select the year you want to plot.

Comment: Again sorry for not being clear enough. I am not looking to select the year using shiny (and in fact have already implemented this in the app:  http://www.seabbs.co.uk/shiny/ExploreGlobalTB/) . I am looking to use plotly's animation abilities over year and dynamically extract the selected frame - from the plotly plot. So this would be capturing the frame from my examples above. The advantage of this is that my app has to redraw the plot which with ggplotly is very slow. Using the built in animation frame from plotly avoids this.

Comment: If this is not possible I may just use plot_ly as the base function for interactive plots. This would not ideal as the static and interactive plots will then be quite different in appearance etc. (the purpose of the app is to showcase package functionality).

Comment: @Sam Abbott. Maybe there is a way to trick it. See edits. Click on one country and click the play button and you will see the table changing.

Comment: Yes this is the solution I have implemented in the app as it currently stands. It looks like it works much better with a plot_ly implementation as the map doesn't have to be redrawn. Using ggplotly leads to a large delay unfortunately, which is why I was trying to use plotly's animation abilities instead. If this is the only way then I will stick with what I have been doing, but I am really interested in dynamically extracting the plotly frame.